# RAILS: How to query if there's already a team formed by an array of users

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm working on an rails API, more specifically in a create operation.

The workflow that I have is this, I have two rails applications, one is an API and the other is an interface. The API manages the different backend operations in order to handle data, store data, and respond in json format to the interface. The interface serves as the frontend, just making http requests to the API in order to display the information.

In my API I have the 3 model listed below:

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :team_users
  has_many :users, through: :team_users
end

class User <ApplicationRecord
  has_many :team_users
  has_many :teams, through: :team_users
end

class TeamUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team
end
```

Basically I'm sending an array of user ids from the Interface to the API and I would like to make a query to find out if there's already a team formed by the users (user ids) that I've passed to the API.

I have already tried to do this:

```
Team.joins(:team_users).where('team_users.user_id' => [3,5])
```

The problem with this query is that it returns every team that contains  the users with id that are equal to 3 or 5. The correct result would be to return a team that has the users 3 and 5 or 5 and 3 as their team members.

Thanks in advance.

#### Update

The original business rule is this, have an aplication that keeps track of trees, so I have a model named tree and when we create a tree whe must say what team created this tree. So I used a multi select user dropdown field with select2 js library that is how I'm passing the user_ids to the API. So the basic idea is to check is theres already a team composed only by the users passed to the API, if there is already a team I use it's id and say that the tree was registered by that team, if there insn't a team with coposed only buy the users I create a new team and reference it's Id to the tree.

Comment: lets try the solution given below and let me know if it is helpful for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can approach the problem in different ways. Scrolling over each `Team` record to check if it contains the associated `user_ids` is pretty straightforward but inefficient:

```
team.user_ids.sort == user_ids.sort
```

But we can make it performant by reversing the process, i.e. iterating over the `user_ids` to find out corresponding teams, taking their intersection of `Team` ids and finally checking if any `team_id` holds those `user_ids`. This line will return **true** if there's already a team formed by the users (`user ids`):

```
user_ids.map { |id| User.find(id).team_ids }.reduce(:&).present?
```

You may include it in the `User` class scope like below:

```ruby
class User < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  def self.team_exists_for?(user_ids)
    # return early

    # what should it return when user_ids is empty
    # return ??? if user_ids.blank?

    # what should it return when any of the id is absent from :users table
    # set_of_all_user_ids = Set.new(User.pluck(:id))
    # set_of_user_ids     = Set.new(user_ids)
    # return ??? unless set_of_user_ids.subset? set_of_all_user_ids

    # finally
    user_ids.map { |id| User.find(id).team_ids }.reduce(:&).present?
  end
  ...
end
```

---

#### Update

So you want to find the team which **only** has those users provided by `user_ids` or create a team with them and assign back to the `Tree` model instance. Combining both approaches described above and defining a scope in the Team model itself seems like a better solution.

```ruby
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  def self.find_or_create_for(user_ids)
    # find all team_ids which contain user_ids (inclusive)
    team_ids = user_ids.map { |id| User.find(id).team_ids }.reduce(:&).flatten

    if team_ids.present? # search for the team which ONLY has 'user_ids'
      team_id = team_ids.find { |id| Team.find(id).user_ids.sort == user_ids.sort }
    end

    return Team.find(team_id) if team_id

    # or create a team with user_ids and return
    team = Team.create! # create a team with required attributes
    team.user_ids = user_ids
    team
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: Just answering the questions above:

1 - The user_ids, or user_id array, will never be empty, it will always be passed to the API.

2 - The user_ids, or user_id array, passed to the API will always have ids of users that are already registered in the API, what this means is, we will never have the condition in wich all the ids passed to the API could be absent from :users table

3 - The scope must return true or false, so if the user_id array passed to the API was [3, 5], the the scpoe must find if theres already a team that  is composed only by users 3 and 5, or users 5 and 3.

Comment: I tried the code and it works but there's  a little problem, lets say I have 2 teams, the first team is composed by users [3, 5], the second team is composed by the users [3, 4, 5]. The problem is that the code finds all the teams with users 3 and 5 as part of they members, so it if we use only this part of the code

`user_ids.map { |id| User.find(id).team_ids }`

it returns an array with team_ids [1(first team), 2 (second team)]. But I need it to return just the id of the first team, because I need to find if there is a team formed only with the user ids passed in the user_id array.

Comment: I detected another problem, i hardcoded a register in postgres to test this. I've created 3 teams,  team 1[3, 5], team 2[5, 3] and team 3 [3, 4, 5]. If I use you code it returns all the 3 teams, when I actually need it to return only team 1.

Comment: got the point you tried to mean in 2nd comment. but from your last comment, you are also concerned with the sequence of user_ids in a team. can you elaborate why team 2[5, 3] is not considered the same as team 1[3, 5]?

Comment: OK, the original problem is this, I have a model named Tree, and each tree is registered by a team.

Comment: I'm sorry that was a mistake in my third  and fourth comments, team [3, 5] is the same team as [5, 3]. I will elaborate the workflow  and the idea behind it in the next comment.

Comment: The original business rule is this,  have an aplication that keeps track of trees, so I have a model named tree and when we create a tree whe must say what team created this tree. So I used a multi select user dropdown field with select2 js library that is how I'm passing the user_ids to the API. So the basic idea is to check is theres already a team composed only by the users passed to the API, if there is already a team I use it's id and say that the tree was registered by that team, if there insn't a team with coposed only buy the users I create a new team and reference it's Id to the tree.

Comment: alright. I updated my answer. please let me know if it works fine.

Comment: This last update of the solution worked really well, thanks a lot.

Comment: Oh I almost forgot, I did one little update in the code, the array of user_ids is converted to string when passed to the API, so before I run this line `team_id = team_ids.find { |id| Team.find(id).user_ids.sort == user_ids.sort }`, I convert the entire user_ids hash to integer using `user_ids.map!(&:to_i)`. That is it.

Answer (score 0):

i have implemented this as

add a field `key: string` on `Team` and in `Team` model

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :team_users
  has_many :users, through: :team_users
  #callback
  before_validation :update_key

  def update_key
    self.key = Team.key_for_users(self.users)
  end

  def self.key_for_users(users)
    users.sort.map(&:id).join("_")
  end
end
```

so basically after this callback whenever you will create a team there will be a key 
for example: -

```
users = [3,5]
```

then `key` in Team will be `3_5`

or users = [5,3]

then `key` in Team will be `5_3`

From this we can easily get the result what you wanted

example: -

```
user_ids = [3,5]
[14] pry(main)> user_ids_simple = user_ids.join('_')
=> "3_5"
[15] pry(main)> user_ids_reverse = user_ids.reverse.join('_')
=> "5_3"
```

and query will be like this: -

```
Team.where("key IN (?)",[user_ids_simple, user_ids_reverse])
```

it may be helpful for you. thanks